# 「楽々と」の「と」: What does と do here?

Tags: meaning, particle-と

Just learned 楽々 from [this](https://vine.co/v/5KeP0Bjtm2q) cat video on vine which says:

> もう楽々にゃ〜

[WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1C) 楽々:

> 楽楽; 楽々 【らくらく】 (adv,adv-to) comfortably; easily
>
> ぼくは手が足の指に楽々とどくよ。 I can easily touch my toes.

Not really sure what `adv-to` means so I looked up to:

[WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1C) と:

> と (prt,conj) (1) if; when; (2) and; (3) with; (4) (See って・1) particle used for quoting (with speech, thoughts, etc.); quoting particle; (n) (5) (abbr) {shogi} (See と金) promoted pawn; (prt) (6) (kyu:) indicates question (sentence end); (P)
>
> (1) このシャンプーを買うと素敵なヘアブラシがついてきます。 This shampoo comes with a nice hair brush.
>
> (2) １２と２４と７と１１の合計は５４です。 The sum of 12, 24, 7 and 11 is 54.
>
> (3) 私はあなたとお話ししてよかった。 I have enjoyed talking to you.
>
> (4) 「美しい」とか「醜い」といった言葉は相対的な用語である。 The words 'beautiful' and 'ugly' are relative terms.

But, none of these definitions seem to fit.

「楽々と」の「と」: What does *to* do here?

Comment: http://nihongo.monash.edu/wwwjdicinf.html#code_tag

Comment: Where did you see 楽々とのと? It makes no sense. 楽々とどく is 楽々+[届]{とど}く. For the usage of と in 楽々と, 次々と, 深々と, のんびりと, しっかりと etc, these threads might be of some help:  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36767/9831 / http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1962/9831

Comment: They mean "the と of 楽々と", I assume. 「楽々と」の「と」

Comment: `「楽々と」の「と」` あぁ、そゆことね～ｗ

Answer (score 4):

For your question, と is a part of とどく，which means *reach*.

However, ぼくは手が足の指に楽々**と**とどくよ。 is also correct.

For adverbs which describe how someone/something does something, と is needed to be added after the adverb, indicating it is an adverb similar to -ly in English, even though 楽々 itself is an adverb.

明鏡国語辞典

```
と（7）
動作や状態の様子を表す
to describe the action or status
```

Answer (score 0):

> 楽々と

```
     揚々と      「 意気揚々と引き揚げる 」
     洋々と      「 洋々と流れる大河 」
```

と is like a [adverb-maker] -- Some of these expressions ( like  揚々と, 洋々と ) sound a bit old-fashioned.

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8/

> と ===
>
> ５ （副詞に付いて新たな副詞をつくり） ある状態を説明する意を表す。
>
> 「そろそろ―歩く」   「そよそよ―風が吹く」
>
> 「ほのぼの―春こそ空に来にけらし天のかぐ山霞たなびく」〈新古今・春上〉